# Debug php Eclipse

Tags: php, debugging, xdebug, eclipse-pdt, zend-debugger

I'm having a very hard time getting a breakpoint to hit in some php code. I don't do much php so might be newbie error.

I've read though the other questions, [PDT Install Instructions](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/articles/debugger/os-php-eclipse-pdt-debug-pdf.pdf), and [XDebug Install Instructions](http://www.xdebug.org/wizard.php)

For both debuggers, the instructions expect a config section to show up in the phpinfo() and it doesn't for me.

Some info about my current setup

- Windows
- AMPPS
- PHP 5.2.17
- Website runs fine

I need some help with things to check or ideas what I might need to do differently.

I'm stuck pretty much for now.

Comment: So have you installed XDebug on your server and added the appropriate config sections to `php.ini`?

Comment: If you don't see XDebug mentioned in the output of `phpinfo()`, it is not loaded.  Check your php.ini file.

Comment: I've edited the php.ini file like the different instructions say, and double checked i'm looking at the correct one. Is there any reason changes like that wouldn't get picked up?

Comment: Installing XDebug is pretty much just grabbing the right debug .dll and referencing it in the php.ini right?

Comment: Did you restart your web server after installing XDebug?

Comment: Ya, restarted apache, AMPPS, and Windows just for fun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two main things that fixed my issues.

1. Turned off Iron PHP Loader
2. copied the non-ts XDebug .dll, even though the php config shows thread safe = enabled. This dll seems to work

The config settings are below for reference:

```
;Stuff to allow debugging in eclipse 
zend_extension="C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.3-5.3-vc9.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=On
xdebug.remote_autostart=On
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_mode=req
```

You do have to make sure and add the extra xdebug configurations or eclipse won't cooperate.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow [this](http://www.ampps.com/blog/how-tos/installing-xdebug-for-all-php-versions-in-ampps-for-windows-1273.html) post to install Xdebug for PHP in AMPPS.